# How to run code in parallell? (Communicating with equipments through VISA and RS232

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, serial-port, spectrogram, visa

I wrote a code to control 3 different devices simultaneously. (Function generator, Thermometer and spectrometer)

And each loop, it reads temperature from thermometer and collects spectrum data from spectrometer. However, for good S/N ratio, spectrometer needs 500ms exposure + 2 times averaging. (in total ~1 sec) This is the bottleneck for running my code and it prevents me collecting more frequent temperature data from thermometer. (It can receive temperature data every 200ms.) Because of this, I can get data points every 1.2 sec. I want more frequent data collection from my thermometer by running these two loops in parallel. (These two parts in the while loop, which I marked in bold. That part is what I want to run in parallel.) Also these two measurement should be done along the real time

Would you teach me how to make this happen? Below is the code I wrote. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
i = 1;
tstart=tic;
k=0;
tnow = 0;
tic
while(tnow<TimeTotal)
    % time(i) = DataAcqTime*(i-1); do not work due to latency in RC232
    if ((tnow > BeforeField) && (tnow < BeforeField + AfterField)) && k==0
        fprintf(fgen, ':OUTPUT:STATe 1'); %Field is on
        k=1;
    end
    
    if (tnow > BeforeField + Fieldtime) && k==1  
        fprintf(fgen, ':OUTPUT:STATe 0'); %Field is off
        k=2;
    end
    
    temp = fscanf(sObject);
    %fscanf(sObject)
    t{i} = temp(7:12);
    data(i) = str2double(t{i});
    tnow = tnow + toc
    time(i)=tnow;
    tic
    NrMeas=0;
while (stoploop==false) & (NrMeas<Measnum)
    S.StartPixel=0;
    S.StopPixel=nPix-1;
    S.IntegrationDelay=0;
    S.CorDynDark=0;
    S.Smoothing=0;
    S.TriggerMode=0;
    S.TriggerSource=0;
    S.TriggerSourceType=0;
    S.SaturationDetection=1;
    myLambda=spectrometer('getlambda');
    spectrometer('measconfig',S);
    spectrometer('measure',1);
    myData=spectrometer('getdata');
    mySat=spectrometer('getsaturated');
    NrMeas=NrMeas+1;
    xlabel('Wavelength [nm]');          
    ylabel('Counts');
%    pause(0.001)  %seconds !!
end

    %plot(myLambda,myData,myLambda,mySat);
    specdata{i}=myData;
    %pause(DataAcqTime); %no small value than 0.1 it fails
    i=i+1;
    tnow = tnow + toc
    time2(i)=tnow; %spectrum time is different from T probe time
    
    tic
end
tEnd = toc(tstart)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parallel computing toolbox is the way to go. 'parfor' function from the toolbox can help you run multiple for loops parallel-y.

An alternative is using Simulink. For your kind of application (3 input streams of data), 'merge' block can be used.

Here's more information about parfor - https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/convert-for-loops-into-parfor-loops.html, and here's more about 'merge' block - https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/merge.html